# How to insert data inside SQlite without providing the primary key?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm building an Android app using Xamarin which uses SQlite as it's primary Data source. I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around the concept of inserting an object into the database. I get "Constraint" error message when I try to insert an object without mentioning the primary key.

For example I have the table "Products" as follows:

```
    class Person
{
    [PrimaryKey, Unique]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String personName { get; set; }
    public int photoId { get; set; }
}
```

if I do `db.Insert(new Person(){personName = "xyz", photoId = 23})` I will get the error message but if I do `db.Insert(new Person(){ID = 1, personName = "xyz", photoId = 23})` data insertion will be successful. How can I insert data without providing the primary key and without making the primary key nullable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `AutoIncrement` attribute to the ID property:

```
class Person
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Unique]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String personName { get; set; }
    public int photoId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If I use AutoIncrement annotation, what will happen to the data I try to insert with their primary key?

Comment: You should be able to add new records without specifying the ID property, and the database will automatically generate a unique ID.

Comment: I meant to ask, if I specify the primary key, which value of the primary key will be added. The one I specified or the one generated by the annotation?

Comment: If you specify, the one you specified will be used.